# "To participate in" or "to participate"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

I would like to use the verbs like "to participate" or "involve" without an object in a clause because I already mentioned what people will participate in preceding clause in a sentence.

Should I add the word "in" at the end of the sentence in this case?

For example:

> 1. There will be various activities during the fair and teachers will
>    encourage students to participate / be involved.
> 2. There will be various activities during the fair and teachers will
>    encourage students to participate in / to be involved in.

Comment: A small correction: you have to say "There will **be** various activities..." because the clause needs a verb.  (*Will* isn't a verb, it's a modal.)

Comment: @stangdon Thanks. It is just  , how to say?, lack of attention. I know "will" is a model.

Comment: *Will* is a verb, a modal verb. I believe stangdon was trying to say that as a modal verb, *will* would normally be followed by another verb in the plain form (in this case *be*), while as a lexical verb that's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

As your sentence is currently constructed, there is no need to add 'in' at the end. This applies whether you use 'participate' or 'be involved'.

If you changed the sentence so that the clause 'there will be various activities during the fair and' was at the end of the sentence, then it would be necessary to (a) slightly amend that clause, and (b) include 'in' after 'participate' or 'be involved'. For example:

> Teachers will encourage students to participate in / to be involved in the various activities during the fair.

Comment: @userr2684291  Thank you. You are quite correct. I have amended my answer to include this correction.